# Do Counter Attack increases transfer over during transmigration

Tags: psp, disgaea

in Disgaea: Afternoon of Darkness, at a certain rank you can get the Dark Assembly to increase the number of counter attacks a character has

if i create a new character and spend all that mana to increase their counter attacks, when i transmigrate them would those counter attacks carry over (ie, a warrior has 2 counter attacks and is transmigrated to a mage who if created anew, has 0 counter attacks), if so, are they affected by the inheritance rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're reset and you'll have to pass the two Counter Attack bills each time in the first Disgaea (both Hour and Afternoon of Darkness). The bills will become available for that character once they meet the prerequisites again (which I forget for now).

Comment: to clarify "The bills will become available for that character once they meet the prerequisites again" the only prerequisite i know of it passing those promotional exams, do i have to redo those for a character when they transmigrate

Comment: @Memor-X yep, every time you reincarnate in Disgaea 1 you'll have to do the exam fights. It's...a good reason not to do it too often.